# Single Primary key in parent table Multiple Foreign key hibernate child table

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a Tables Category, Employee 
Employee Table has the columns

```
  Id   Name
  ---  ----
  1    Programmer
  2    Manager
  3    juniorprogrammer
  4    seniorprogrammer

 Child table 
  id  categoryid  subcategoryid  empid  Dateofjoin 
  --  ----------  -------------  -----  ----------
  1      2           Null         177     12-Dec-13
  2      1            3           179     12-Dec-13
  3      1            4           180     12-Nov-12
```

i created a Pojo class for these two tables, i have to do a select query from this tables .

possible input parameter (empid)

i need to get the relevant name for the categoryid and subcategoryid using hibernate

I am new to Hibernate can any one help me to do a select query.

Thanks,
Mithun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to read about is [Hibernate Enumerated Types](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-enum-type-mapping-example)

In short there are several ways to do what you want, I can suggest 2: **using java enum** and **separate table**:

1. Don't create Category table, but replace categoryid column with `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` annotated field in java. In this way hibernate will take the enum .toString() method result as database column name.
2. If you need Category table then you need to create another `@Entity @Table` Category POJO to represent your Category table, and then map it as `@ManyToOne`

If you don't consider any other columns in Category table I recomend you to follow the 1st way. (Unless you have a task exactly like this)